# Why does Keras Bayesion Hypermodel puts None values in lists and cant create model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, bayesian, hyperparameters

I use this hypermodel:

```
class MyHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def build(self, hp):    
    
        input_shape      = (2, None, 1)
        activation       = "relu"

        arc              = hp.Choice("arc", values=["common", "res", "att", "att_res"])
        dropout_rate     = hp.Float("dropout rate", 0, 0.15)
        nb_blocks        = hp.Int("nb_blocks", 2, 7)
        optimizer        = hp.Choice("optimizer", values=["RMSprop", "adam"])
        batch_norm       = hp.Choice("batch_norm", values=[False, True])
        pooling          = hp.Choice("pooling", values=["GAP", "GSP", "SPP", "GMP"]) 

        dense_list = []
        with hp.conditional_scope("pooling", ["SPP"]):
            if pooling == "SPP":
                dense_depth = hp.Int("dense_depth", 1, 4)
                for i in range(dense_depth):
                    dense_units = hp.Choice(f"dense_units_d{i}", values=[4, 8, 16, 32])
                    dense_list.append(dense_units)
        # specify kernel size fo reach block
        kernel_list = []   
        filter_list=[]
        with hp.conditional_scope("nb_blocks", [2]):        
            if nb_blocks > 1:
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b1", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b1", 1, 2)
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b2", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b2", 1, 2)
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_1", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_2", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
        with hp.conditional_scope("nb_blocks", [3]):        
            if nb_blocks > 2:
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b3", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b3", 1, 2)
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_3", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
        with hp.conditional_scope("nb_blocks", [4]):        
            if nb_blocks > 3:
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b4", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b4", 1, 2)
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_4", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
        with hp.conditional_scope("nb_blocks", [5]):        
            if nb_blocks > 4:
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b5", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b5", 1, 2)
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_5", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
        with hp.conditional_scope("nb_blocks", [6]):        
            if nb_blocks > 5:
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b6", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b6", 1, 2)
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_6", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
        with hp.conditional_scope("nb_blocks", [7]):        
            if nb_blocks > 6:
                kernel_x = hp.Int(f"kernel_x_b7", 1, 10)
                kernel_y = hp.Int(f"kernel_y_b7", 1, 2) 
                kernel_list.append((kernel_y, kernel_x))
                filters_per_block = hp.Choice(f"filters_for_block_7", values= [32, 64, 128, 256])
                filter_list.append(filters_per_block)
        
        
        print(arc,dropout_rate, nb_blocks, optimizer, batch_norm, pooling, dense_list,  kernel_list, filter_list)
        # build model based on hp                             
        # define INput
        input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape, name="Input")
        x=input_layer

        # choose convolutinal architecture
        with hp.conditional_scope("arc", ["common"]):
            if arc == "common":
                for i, filters in enumerate(filter_list):
                    conv = conv_block(x, filters, (kernel_list[i][0], kernel_list[i][1]), dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    x = conv
        with hp.conditional_scope("arc", ["res"]):
            if arc == "res":
                for i, filters in enumerate(filter_list):
                    conv = res_conv_block(x, filters, kernel_list[i], dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    x = conv
        with hp.conditional_scope("arc", ["att"]):
            if arc == "att":
                for i, filters in enumerate(filter_list):
                    conv1 = conv_block(x, filters, kernel_list[i], dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    conv2 = conv_block(conv1, filters, kernel_list[i], dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    att = attention_block(conv2, conv1, filters)
                    x = att
        with hp.conditional_scope("arc", ["att_res"]):
            if arc == "att_res":
                for i, filters in enumerate(filter_list):
                    conv1 = res_conv_block(x, filters, kernel_list[i], dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    conv2 = res_conv_block(conv1, filters, kernel_list[i], dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    att = attention_block(conv2, conv1, filters)
                    conv3 = conv_block(att, filters, kernel_list[i], dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
                    x = conv3
        # add pooling method to achieve fixed size unrelated to input size
        if pooling == "GAP":
            gate = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            GAP = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(gate)
            x = GAP
        if pooling == "SPP":
            spp_layer = SpatialPyramidPooling2D([[2, 2], [1, 2],[1, 1]], name="SPP")(x)
            flatten = Flatten()(spp_layer)
            x=flatten
        if pooling == "GSP":
            gate = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            GSP = Lambda(sum_pooling)(gate)
            x=GSP
        if pooling == "GMP":
            gate = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding='same')(x)
            GMP = GlobalMinPool2D()(gate)
            x=GMP

        # add dense layers if required
        if pooling == "SPP":
            for i, units in enumerate(dense_list):
                dense = Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
                drop = Dropout(dropout_rate)(dense)
                x = drop
            x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)


        # create model   
        model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=x)
        # model.summary()
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mape", metrics=['mse', "mape"])
        return model
```

I intentionally don't use a loop for the kernel_sizes, so the optimizer knows which parameters are used and which not.

I would expect it to build the model, however I get an Error:

```
 The optimizer manages to build the first two models but the third model is not built, due to the None values in the lists.
```

However I don't understand why these are there in the first place.

This is the output print I used in the Hypermodel:

```
common 0.0 2 RMSprop 0 GAP [] [(1, 1), (1, 1)] [32, 32]
common 0.0 2 RMSprop 0 SPP [4] [(1, 1), (1, 1)] [32, 32]
common 0.0 3 RMSprop 0 GAP [] [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (None, None), (None, None), (None, None), (None, None)] [32, 32, 32, None, None, None, None]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


This is the Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Programme\Python\envs\gpuTEST\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in normalize_tuple(value, n, name, allow_zero)
     85       try:
---> 86         int(single_value)
     87       except (ValueError, TypeError):

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18156\3375396705.py in build(self, hp)
    155             if arc == "common":
    156                 for i, filters in enumerate(filter_list):
--> 157                     conv = conv_block(x, filters, (kernel_list[i][0], kernel_list[i][1]), dropout=dropout_rate, batch_norm=batch_norm, activation = "relu")
    158                     x = conv
    159         with hp.conditional_scope("arc", ["res"]):



ValueError: The `kernel_size` argument must be a tuple of 2 integers. Received: (None, None)including element None of type <class 'NoneType'>
```